# Hosting ASP.net web api (odatacontroller) inside silverlight site

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-web-api

I want to expose some odata resources from my silverlight site. WCF data services doesn't provide the features I need so I need to use ASP.NET web api instead.

Is it possible to host such ASP.Net web api inside silverlight site?

The requested support is: Filtering the IQueryable of the resource before returning the results. In WCF data service you can use only queryinspectors which filter each row separatly which will affect performance.

Thanks!
Eran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host ASP.NET Web API in any ASP.NET Web Application, so it will work. Yes, it's possible to filter the IQueryable before the data is returned. Take a look at the OData samples in the Web API source code for some examples of how that can be done. Your assumption about WCF is incorrect, a QueryInspector modifies the LINQ expression before it goes to the data store, so the data is filtered in the store and not in memory.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will try what you suggested. I know that QueryInspector  modifies the expression but in my scenario I need to check if the record exists in a list that is stored in the memory. I don't want to send that list to the database since it might be a long list.